# Add column value to next column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My sql table is

```
Week    Year    Applications
1       2017    0
2       2017    10
3       2017    20
4       2017    50
5       2017    0
1       2018    10
2       2018    0
3       2018    40
4       2018    50
5       2018    10
```

And I want SQL query which give below output

```
Week    Year    Applications
1       2017    0
2       2017    10
3       2017    30
4       2017    80
5       2017    80
1       2018    10
2       2018    10
3       2018    50
4       2018    100
5       2018    110
```

Can anyone help me to write below query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `SUM() OVER` to get cumulative sum:

```
SELECT *, SUM(Applications) OVER(PARTITION BY Year ORDER BY Week)
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want a cumulative sum:

```
select week, year,
       sum(applications) over (partition by year order by week) as cumulative_applications
from t;
```